# VBA microsoft word

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, macros

I want to protect my vba cod in a word file, not by a password... but by making this code unviewable.
I want users to get message no1 not message no2 when they try to see the code.

msg 1: project is unviewable

msg 2: Password

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting

> Project is unwievable

for VBA code is not a implicit setting in Office, but a consequence of trying to open VBA module of a file opened as an add-in. (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23821295/word-vba-getting-project-is-unviewable-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017813/word-vba-project-is-unviewable)).

Users closing the file and opening as a normal file will be able to access the code.